# How do you replace values in one column with values in another when condition is not met with Python

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, str-replace, pandas-loc

I have some inconsistent data with 5 columns. The two I'm focussing on are - 'Account Name' and 'User ID'. All the Account names should contain a 7 character string. If it doesn't I want to replace if with the ID in 'User ID'.
Example data:

| Account Name | User ID |
| --- | --- |
| JB05737 | JB05737 |
| bg@***.com | BG49568 |
| GV95577 | GV95577 |

I want to get:

| Account Name | User ID |
| --- | --- |
| JB05737 | JB05737 |
| BG49568 | BG49568 |
| GV95577 | GV95577 |

I have tried the following codes and got errors:

`Reports.loc[Reports['Account Name'].astype(str).map(len) != 7] = Reports[Reports['User ID']].astype(str)`

`Reports.loc[Reports['Account Name'].astype(str).map(len) != 7].replace(Reports['User ID'])`

````
    if (Reports.loc['Account Name'].map(len) != 7):
        Reports.loc[i, 'Account Name']==Reports.loc[i, 'User ID']```

```Reports.loc[Reports['Account Name'].map(len) != 7, 'Account Name] = Reports.loc[Reports['Account Name'].map(len) != 7,'User ID']```


The errors have included: shape errors, invalid syntax, ...not in index

Any suggestions?
````

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this..

```
for col1, id in df.itertuples(index=False):
  print("Iterating both columns:\n",a, b)
  if len(id) > 7:
    df['col1'].replace('col1', 'id')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error 'Too many values to unpack'. 
```for Reports['Account Name'], i in Reports.itertuples(index=False):
    if len(i) > 7:
        Reports['Account Name'].replace('Account Name', 'User ID')```

Comment: Yes it was pseudocode, so it was more to give you a idea then working code

Comment: This code worked
```Reports['Account Name']=Reports['User ID'].where(Reports['Account Name'].map(len)>7,Reports['User ID'])```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

`Reports['Account Name']=Reports['User ID'].where(Reports['Account Name'].map(len)>7,Reports['User ID'])`